# My windows 7 looks like windows xp

Tags: windows-7

I was doing some school work on my laptop (Aero Themes worked fine) then my Antivirus (ESET NOD32) asked me if it can reboot my laptop to complete clean up or something like that. So i saved my work closed everything then clicked yes.

Then when it booted up everything looked like Windows XP. I tried to change the theme in personalize but i can't click any Aero Themes. They're blacked out and only the classic ones can be clicked.

Here's the list of the things I did but failed:

- I tried the thing in the task manager in the services tab to start themes service but it wont work (It says access is denied)
- I also tried the thing where they say my graphic card cant support the themes but my graphic card is working properly (AMD)
- I also tried the troubleshooting in the Aero Themes thing it showed me the error but cant fix it.

How could I get Aero Themes enabled again?

Comment: What are those "things" (please be more specific) and if the troubleshooter is able to detect the error, what does it say it is and what error do you get if you try to fix it?

Comment: Aero requires a compatible graphics driver. Likely what has happened something has messed the driver up. I would also point out that a screenshot would likely result in better answers being submitted.